# Spatial Data from Postgis to Java/REST with RestEasy + Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, geospatial, resteasy

I have a service that retrieves a geospatial data (linestring) from postgis and i'd like to send this geospatial data as JSON data beyond a REST Service with RestEasy + Jackson. Someone know how to transform this spatial data to JSON?

My Entity:

```
public class Route {

    ...
private LineString caminho;

public Rota() {
}

public Rota(Integer id, Usuario usuario, String descricao, LineString lineString) {
    this.id = id;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.caminho = lineString;
}

// getters and setters

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
public LineString getCaminho() {
    return caminho;
}

public void setCaminho(LineString caminho) {
    this.caminho = caminho;
}

    // hashcode and equals method
}
```

My REST service:

```
@Inject
private RotaBC rotaBC;

@GET
@Path("/rotas/{idrota}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Route show(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return rotaBC.show(Integer.parseInt(id));
}
```

The error:

15:05:16,447 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sharecar].[default]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException$Reference from [Module "org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl:main" from local module loader @1d332b (roots: /opt/demoiselle/server/jboss-7.1/modules)]

...

at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:166)

...

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)

Answer (score 0):

The error you have suggests either missing Jackson jar, or conflicted versions. Latter is probably more likely -- if code to run is compiled using a later Jackson version, and classpath has an earlier version, this could result.

Comment: I believe Jackson didn't give support to geometry columns.

Comment: I don't know about that (depends on how they look), but the exception quite clearly points to class loading issue, which occur before any JSON or data-binding processing happens.